# Get title/name of master if google slide script?

Tags: google-slides-api

With Google Slide script, How I can get the name (not title) of the master, and the name of each template in the master ?

Comment: Can I ask you about `Google Slide script` and `the name of each template in the master`?

Comment: `master_layouts.forEach(function(layout)
    {
        Logger.log("Layout name =" + layout.getLayoutName())
}`
return generated name (`Layout name =CUSTOM`), not the user interface name.